# Attach multiple v-models to the loop of dynamic child components in vuejs 2

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Recently I ran into a problem, where I had to display many different components inside a loop, but: each of them should share it's state with parent (kinda knockout.js style). I was digging thru the docs where clearly was pointed out, that Vue.js pass properties one way down to childs, and those can eventually speak with some events. Also, docs says that there can be only one v-model per component, so finally I came up with something like this:

`<li :is="field.type" v-for="(field, i) in fields" :key="i" :title="field.title" v-on:title-change="title = $event" :somevalue="field.somevalue" v-on:somevalue-change="somevalue = $event"></li>`

And so on... Yet, after fifth parameter I quickly realized that the code is basically messy. Is there some less messy way to attach multiple two-way data bindings to child components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution happened to be a `.sync` method and proper naming of events. While sync has been deprecated and removed in vue.js 2, since 2.3 version has been rewritten and added again in some similar form. As in fact it's only a syntatic sugar, my component now looks more decent I believe.

```
<ol>
    <li :is="field.type" 
        v-for="(field, i) in fields"
        :key="field.id"
        v-bind.sync="field"
        v-on:remove="fields.splice(i, 1)"></li>
</ol>



Vue.component('bool', {
  template: '\
    <li>\
      <input type="text" v-bind:value="title" @input="$emit(\'update:title\', $event.target.value)">\
      <button v-bind:value="value" @click="$emit(\'update:value\', !$event.target.value)" :class="{active: value}">{{value}}</button>\
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" v-bind:checked="istrue" @change="$emit(\'update:istrue\', $event.target.checked)">\
      <button @click="$emit(\'remove\')">Remove</button>\
    </li>\
  ',
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  props: ['title', 'value', 'availablevalues']
})
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://vuex.vuejs.org/, depending on how often and much shared data you have in your application. Also, objects and arrays are passed to child components by reference, meaning that if 2 different components have the same object reference, if one of them updates the object the other component will be updated as well. This doesn't work for value types like strings or integers though. You could also wrap your shared data in one bigger object.